# Control FCM push notification presentation when iOS app is in background

Tags: swift3, push-notification, xcode8, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios10

FCM provides a callback for the notifications when the app is in foreground mode, I want to know how can I control when to show or not show a notification or change the title/body before showing it in the system tray when is in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS to change title / body of the notification when received while the app is in background you need to use the `mutable_content` parameter and the `UNNotificationServiceExtension` service extension

`mutable_content` option:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

`UNNotificationServiceExtension` service extension
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html